# Fade In and Fade out Effects with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I have a map on my webpage with the locations our company currently serves. There are some JavaScript effects that make the names of the locations we serve fade in and out on the map and then icons for our location appear. I need it so that the icons still fade in, but the names of the locations do not fade in and out when the webpage is loaded. If anyone could help that would be awesome!

Here is the JavaScript for the map effects:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function get_random(items){
    return items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
}

$('#map').append('<div id="animate" class="animatedText1"></ul>');
var x = 0;
var counter = 0;
var xpos = 0;
var ypos = 0;


$('.col_3 li').each(function(){

        xpos = Math.random() * (630 - this.offsetWidth);
        ypos = Math.random() * (404 - this.offsetHeight);
        $("#animate").append("<div class='transparent' id='efx_" + x + "' style='top:"      + ypos + "px;left:" + xpos + "px'>" + $(this).text() + "</div>");
        $("#efx_" + x).find("span").removeClass("red");
        $("#efx_" + x).delay(Math.floor(Math.random() *    1000)).fadeTo(Math.floor(Math.random() * 8000)+1000, .7,  function(){
            $(this).fadeOut(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000)+500, function(){
                $(this).remove();
                counter++;
                if(counter == $('.col_3 li').length-1){
                    $("#animate").hide();
                }
                if(counter == $('.col_3 li').length){
                    $("#animate").addClass('with_icon').fadeIn(2000);
                    $(".icons").show()
                }
            });
        });
    x++;
});

});
```

Here is some of the HTML:

```
<?php
$page = "contact";
$sub_page = "locations";
$banner = "banner-contactus";
?>
  <div class="page inter">
     <?php include "php_includes/header.php" ?>
   <div class="content clearfix">
     <div class="content_header">
        <h1>IN CITIES NEAR YOU.</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="left_col">
         <div class="one_col">
            <div id="map">
            <div class="icons">
          <div id="reg02" class="reg">
            <div class="info">
          <p class="state">Arizona</p>
          <p>Phoenix, AZ</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: This would be a really good question, *if* you also provided a JSFiddle with sample HTML :)

Comment: can you clarify? you want the names to be displayed when page is loaded and only the icons to fade in?

Comment: for the selector used for _names of the locations_, make css property as display:none;

Comment: @webkit No I don't want the names to show up at all, just for the icons to "fade in" on the map.

Comment: @jeekonline I will give that a try right now, and I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I don't know if I am allow to post all of the html because it is our company site, but I'll try to get JSFiddle made.

Comment: @user3726748 if you still need help with this, I have to see at least a snippet of your html with the elements you want to fade and the ones you don't... On its face it seems that all you need to do is NOT FADE the elements with the names and just leave them hidden.. so whats the issue?